# React Testing Library userEvent not waiting for render updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a simple RTL test failing.

Given this trivial `TodoList` component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/fa";

interface TodoItemProps {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
  onToggle: () => void;
  onDelete: () => void;
}

const TodoItem: React.FC<TodoItemProps> = ({
  text,
  completed,
  onToggle,
  onDelete,
}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div className="flex items-center py-2">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="mr-2"
          checked={completed}
          onChange={onToggle}
        />
        <span
          className={`text-lg ${completed ? "line-through text-gray-400" : ""}`}
        >
          {text}
        </span>
        <button
          className="ml-auto"
          onClick={onDelete}
          data-testid="complete-todo"
        >
          <FaTrash />
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

const TodoList: React.FC<{
  initialValues?: string[];
}> = ({ initialValues }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<{ text: string; completed: boolean }[]>(
    initialValues
      ? initialValues.map((v) => ({ text: v, completed: false }))
      : []
  );
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState<string>("");

  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    if (!newTodo.trim()) {
      return;
    }
    setTodos([...todos, { text: newTodo.trim(), completed: false }]);
    setNewTodo("");
  };

  const handleToggleTodo = (index: number) => {
    setTodos((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((todo, i) =>
        i === index ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
    );
  };

  const handleDeleteTodo = (index: number) => {
    setTodos((prevState) => prevState.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4 p-6 max-w-md">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add a todo..."
          className="py-2 px-3 rounded-md bg-gray-100 w-full mr-2"
          value={newTodo}
          onChange={(e) => setNewTodo(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md"
          onClick={handleAddTodo}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <TodoItem
            key={index}
            text={todo.text}
            completed={todo.completed}
            onToggle={() => handleToggleTodo(index)}
            onDelete={() => handleDeleteTodo(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

The following test fails when getting the `todoItem` with `getByText`.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

it("adds a new todo item", async () => {
    render(<TodoList />);
    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");
    userEvent.click(input);
    userEvent.keyboard("Buy milk");
    const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Add" });
    userEvent.click(button);
    const todoItem = screen.getByText("Buy milk");
    expect(todoItem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

If I use a `pause` helper function and call it after **each** `userEvent`, then the test passes.

```
const pause = () => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 100);
    });
  };

  it("adds a new todo item", async () => {
    render(<TodoList />);
    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");
    userEvent.click(input);
    await pause();
    userEvent.keyboard("Buy milk");
    await pause();
    const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Add" });
    userEvent.click(button);
    await pause();
    const todoItem = screen.getByText("Buy milk");
    expect(todoItem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

I was under the impression that `userEvent`s are made specifically to wait for state update, but here it seems like it's still not enough to have the `todoItem` appear in the DOM in time for the query.

Why is this happening, and what would be a better solution than using the `pause`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to await the individual userEvent calls. I'm pretty sure this will achieve your aim.

Failing that, for the final assertion, you could import waitFor (from RTL) and do `await waitFor(()=>{expect(...)})`. Think the first option should see you good though.

Comment: Right, completed missed that userEvents need to be awaited, thanks.